# button disabled asp.net in a form

Tags: asp.net

i tried to disable double click but when i empty one of the cells and fill it with whitespaces focus isnt working and the button is still disabled.
what should i do?
thanks.

```
 <div class="ContactGlobalDiv">
            <%if (Request.QueryString["modeSend"] == "thanks")
              {%>
                <div class="ThanksForm"><%=((MRW.BLL.Content.Page)MRW.Models.ContentModelServices.LoadByID(239)).Data.Text1%></div>
            <%} else{%>
            <div class="TopFormLabelNewsLetter">
            <img src="../../../000Frames/site/images/topstars.png" alt="צור קשר - שמיים וארץ"/>
            <div id="labelTopFormHome">הרשמה לניוזלטר</div>רוצים לקבל מידע ועדכונים מאתנו? <br />מלאו פרטיכם כאן
            </div>

            <div class="qtextBoxDiv">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="qtxtbox" ID="Name" Text="שם" onfocus="$('#SendButton7').prop('disabled', false); if (this.value=='שם') this.value=''; " onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='שם';$('#SendButton7').prop('disabled', false);"  />
                <div class="validate">
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="Name" SetFocusOnError="true" ValueToCompare="שם" Operator="NotEqual" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ContactA"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CompareValidator22" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="Name" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ContactA" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="qtextBoxDiv">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="qtxtbox" ID="Mail" Text="מייל" onfocus="$('#SendButton7').prop('disabled', false); if (this.value=='מייל') this.value=''; " onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='מייל';$('#SendButton7').prop('disabled', false);"  />
                <div class="validate">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="Mail" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ContactA"/>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailValid" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ControlToValidate="Mail" ErrorMessage="אימייל לא חוקי" ValidationGroup="ContactA" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="qtextBoxDiv">
                <asp:Button runat="server"  ValidationGroup="ContactA"  ID="SendButton7" Text="שלח" onclick="SendButton_Click" CssClass="qSendButton" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;"/>
            </div>
            <%} %>
    </div>
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled is not an attribute which you can set true or false, if the disabled attribute exists on a control it will be disabled, you need to remove the disabled property/attribute from the button to enable it again.

All of these variations will disable the button:

```
disabled
disabled="true"
disabled="false"
disabled=""
disabled="anything"
```

In your case, use **.removeProp()** (http://api.jquery.com/removeprop/)